# Change word inside link using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following link:

```
<a class="some_class" 
href="https://example.com/text/sometext2/">
```

I need to change the word "text" to "sometext1" using JavaScript

Thanks!

Comment: You mean you need to change the path in `href`?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I need to change href="https://example.com/text/sometext2/" to href="https://example.com/sometext1/sometext2/".

But, I cannot change the entire link because the word "sometext2" is dynamic.

Comment: Is there more than one link with the same class name? And if there are more similar links, and they contain `text` in the path, are they supposed to be changed too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) to get a reference to your links, then iterate over the links using `forEach()` and use [`elem.getAttribute('href')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) and [`elem.setAttribute('href', value)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to get and set the `href` attribute on each link.

To change the value, use [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regex:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a.some_class').forEach(link => {
  const href = link.getAttribute('href').replace(/\/text\//, '/sometext1/');
  link.setAttribute('href', href);
  console.log(href);
});
```

```html
<a class="some_class" href="https://example.com/text/sometext2/">A link</a>
<a class="some_class" href="https://example.com/text/sometext2/">A link</a>
<a class="some_class" href="https://example.com/text/sometext2/">A link</a>
<a class="some_class" href="https://example.com/text/sometext2/">A link</a>
```

Or more simply:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a.some_class').forEach(link => {
    link.href = link.href.replace(/\/text\//, '/sometext1/');
});
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but unfortunately I cannot change the html so I cannot add the "Change link" button.

Comment: @Gabriel Meisel, the button is just here for the demo. Check the code executes by the click handler

Comment: Ok got it, it worked! But I have multiple links in the same page that I need to replace "text" for "SomeText1". It is the same replacement for all the links, but the code only does the change on the first link. All links have the same class. @jo_va

Comment: @Gabriel Meisel, I updated the anser to work with multiple links, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in JavaScript I believe by doing `document.getElementById("your-button").href="your-page.html";`.

Comment: The link doesn't seem to have an id, though.

Comment: I didn't know if there were multiple links needing to be changed. If that is so, use Adrien's solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change all the links having `some_class` class, you could do this :

```
document.querySelectorAll("a.some_class").forEach(a => a.href.replace(/\btext\b/g, "sometext1"));
```

The `/\btext\b/g` regex will match every 'text' word in your string :

- `\b` asserts a **word boundary**, so if text is included in a word it will not match
- The `g` switch makes the regex **global**, so it does not stop on first match

Answer (score 0):

You would access the href attribute of that element. Then transform the text however you need to do so. In this case we are identifying the text by other delimiters.

```
var element = document.querySelector('a.some_class');
var href = element.getAttribute('href')
href = href.replace(/\/text\//, '/sometext1/');
element.setAttribute('href', href');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first get the element and use setAttribute method of the element where you can replace your old value

```js
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
a.setAttribute("href",a.getAttribute('href').replace("text","SomeText1"));
```

```html
<a class="some_class" 
href="https://example.com/text/sometext2/">
test
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Maulik this worked!

But I have multiple links in the same page that I need to replace "text" for "SomeText1". It is the same replacement for all the links, but the code only does the change on the first link.

Comment: All links have the same class btw